@clerk/clerk-expo ~ setProfileImage(): File is invalid. must be a valid base64 encoded image
I am trying to update the profile image of my clerk/expo using react-native with expo-router. I use the ImagePicker from expo-image-picker and use the returned URI to try and update the profile image but to no avail. It keeps giving me this error: File is invalid. must be a valid base64 encoded image.
import { useUser } from "@clerk/clerk-expo";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import Spinner from "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const EditProfile = () => {
    const { user } = useUser();
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(user?.firstName);
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(user?.lastName);
    const [currentPassword, setCurrentPassword] = useState("");
    const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState("");
    const [image, setImage] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const onUpdatePress = async () => {
        setLoading(true);

        try {
            if (firstName && lastName) {
                await user?.update({
                    firstName: firstName!,
                    lastName: lastName!,
                });
            }

            if (currentPassword && newPassword) {
                await user?.updatePassword({
                    currentPassword,
                    newPassword,
                });
            }

      if (image) {
        const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(image, { encoding: 'base64' });
        console.log(base64);
        await user?.setProfileImage({ file: base64 });
      }

            user?.reload();
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error.errors[0].message);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 0.1,
    });

    console.log(result.assets![0].uri);

        if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri)
        }
    };

    return (
        <ScrollView className="flex-1">
            <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 pb-3">
                <Spinner visible={loading} />
                <View className="h-[240px] items-center justify-center space-y-3">
                    <View className="relative">
                        <Image
                            source={{
                                uri: image || user?.imageUrl,
                            }}
                            alt="Profile Photo"
                            className="rounded-full w-52 h-44"
                        />
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={pickImage}
                            className="absolute p-1 rounded-full right-5 bottom-3 bg-light-orange"
                        >
                            <Feather name="edit-3" size={20} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View className="px-4 space-y-3">
                    <View className="gap-1">
                        <Text>First Name</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Your First Name"
                            className="px-3 py-2 border rounded-xl"
                            value={firstName!}
                            onChangeText={(text) => setFirstName(text)}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View className="gap-1">
                        <Text>Last Name</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Your Last Name"
                            className="px-3 py-2 border rounded-xl"
                            value={lastName!}
                            onChangeText={(text) => setLastName(text)}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View className="gap-1">
                        <Text>Current Password</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Your Password"
                            className="px-3 py-2 border rounded-xl"
                            autoCapitalize="none"
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            value={currentPassword}
                            onChangeText={(text) => setCurrentPassword(text)}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View className="gap-1">
                        <Text>New Password</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Your Password"
                            className="px-3 py-2 border rounded-xl"
                            autoCapitalize="none"
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            value={newPassword}
                            onChangeText={(text) => setNewPassword(text)}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View className="gap-1">
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={onUpdatePress}
                            className="py-4 bg-main-orange rounded-xl"
                        >
                            <Text
                                style={{ fontFamily: "Poppins_500Medium" }}
                                className="text-base text-center text-off-white"
                            >
                                Update
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

export default EditProfile;


I have tried using react-native-fs, react-native-image-base64, expo-file-system as you can see in my code. I also tried this:
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 0.1,
      base64: true
    });

I am using an android phone to test all this btw if that's relevant.
can you give me some tips?

Try following this guide: https://stack.convex.dev/uploading-files-from-react-native-or-expo.
The trick here is to upload a blob, which you can get from the selected image through running a fetch on the local URI.

The base64 string coming from ImagePicker is not valid (you can check it by copying the string and paste it here https://jaredwinick.github.io/base64-image-viewer/?ref=tiny-helpers). It is missing some parameters in front of it like the mime-type and the encoding. I solved this issue in this way:
async function onPickImage() {
  try {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 4],
      quality: 0.1,
      base64: true,
    });

    if (!result.canceled && result.assets[0].base64) {
      const base64 = result.assets[0].base64;
      const mimeType = result.assets[0].mimeType;

      const image = `data:${mimeType};base64,${base64}`;

      await user?.setProfileImage({
        file: image,
      });
    }
  } catch (err: any) {
    alert(err.errors[0].message);
  }
}

